# How to give role dependencies path in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

I want to include role dependency. However looks like it downloads from galaxy. I already have a role in pc. How do I provide a path to it in "meta" file.

Say, I want to install a ROLE_B which is dependent on ROLE_A.

Here is the structure I have.

```
~/Ansible/Playbook.yml
~/Ansible/Roles/ROLE_B
~/Ansible/Roles/ROLE_A


Meta-file of ROLE_B:
---
dependencies: [
  - ~/Ansible/Roles/ROLE_A
]
```

Any idea if it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect. Either you should use YAML or JSON to define a list, but not both.

```
dependencies:
  - ~/Ansible/Roles/ROLE_A
```

---

But you don't need to provide a full path to the roles if they are in `roles` directory. So the following should be sufficient:

```
dependencies:
  - ROLE_A
```